# Making header full width when making the browser window very short

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking at the theme [eleven40](http://demo.studiopress.com/eleven40/) from studiopress.

When I shorten the browser window a lot (being a mobile responsive theme), the logo goes to 100% width making the menu fall beautifully under.

Any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is CSS3 media queries. Check for example this article on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

In this particular case next rule does the job:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    ...
    #title {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 18px 0 17px;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: to find out, just get google chrome, open developer tools and resize the window...

Comment: Ty very much, are these techniques cross browser? Do most mobile phones see this type of code?

Comment: More or less. Check support http://caniuse.com/#search=media+queries. IE supports starting from version 9. So users of IE7 will always see a normal page without this cool features.

Answer (score 1):

This technique is called [Responsive Design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/) and relies on [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

In this case, they are changing this:

```
.header-image #title-area,
.header-image #title,
.header-image #title a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 265px;
}
```

to this:

```
#title {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 18px 0 17px;
}

#title-area {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

when the browser is less than `800px` wide. (see [their CSS file](http://demo.studiopress.com/eleven40/wp-content/themes/eleven40/style.css) and search for `#title`). The two most important parts of this are removing the `float` and setting the width to `100%`.

Comment: Ty very much, are these techniques cross browser? Do most mobile phone see this type of code?

Comment: @dfsq Got to this a bit before I did and their answer is very similar to mine. They have you on the right track, but we both gave you links to check out so you should do that first and investigate for yourself.